# Openfire deletes pubsub nodes after one day (not after server restart or deleting cache)

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire

After one day all pubsub nodes I created  are gone and I can't retrieve them via iq stanzas. But they are still in the mysql database. Anyway when I create the nodes they are retrievable via xml iq stanzas..

Has anybody an idea what happens?

Edit1: I noticed that a leaf node which I created with the standard configuration does not disappear after one day. So I think it is a configuration issue on my side.

I retrieve pubsub nodes with:

```
<iq type='get' to='pubsub.server.local'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>
</iq>
```

or for particular node with:

```
<iq type='get' to='pubsub.server.local'>
  <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node='Collection1'/>
</iq>
```

That's not the problem since after the creation I get all the information about the nodes I created. I can't retrieve them after one day. Maybe my configuration is wrong or the server deletes something like the cache after one day? But I tried to delete the cache manually and I can retrieve the newly created nodes. As I said they are not retrievable after one day.  This is really strange..

Edit2: The configuration

I create collection/collection/leaf the following configurations:

```
<iq to='pubsub.server.local' type="set">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<create node="Weird"/> 
<configure><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"> 
<field var="FORM_TYPE"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#node_config</value> </field>
<field var="pubsub#node_type"><value>collection</value></field>  
<field var="pubsub#title"><value>NodeName</value> </field>
<field var="pubsub#description"><value>NodeDescription</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#leaf_node_association_policy"><value>whitelist</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#leaf_node_association_whitelist"><value>owner@server.local</value></field>
</x></configure> </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Am I allowed to put the owner's JID into the whitelist?

then I create and configure the collection in the first collection which has a "node" attribute set to collection_1234 for identification reasons and the "name" attribute set to a readable name Collection2

```
<iq to='pubsub.server.local' type="set">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<create node="collection_1234"/> 
<configure><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"> 
<field var="FORM_TYPE"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#node_config</value> </field>
<field var="pubsub#node_type"><value>collection</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#collection"><value>Weird</value></field>   
<field var="pubsub#title"><value>Collection2</value> </field>
<field var="pubsub#deliver_payloads"><value>1</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#leaf_node_association_whitelist"><value>user1@server.local</value></field>
</x></configure> </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Must the payload type of the child (here Atom) be the same as in the parent collection node (here none)?

then a leaf in the Collection2:

```
<iq to="pubsub.server.local" type="set">     
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
<create node="leaf_1234"/> 
<configure><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"> 
<field var="FORM_TYPE"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#node_config</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#collection"><value>collection_1234</value></field> 
<field var="pubsub#type"><value>http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#persist_items"><value>1</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#max_items"><value>-1</value></field>
<field var="pubsub#type"><value>http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom</value>
<field var="pubsub#publisher">
  <value>nodeowner@server.local</value>
  <value>anotheruser@server.local</value>
</field>
</x>
</configure> </pubsub>
</iq>
```

Can I configure the node owner to be a publisher? 
I omit the #publish_model variable because the value publishers is standard.

Comment: I have never seen this issue, and nothing like it has been reported, so I suspect that this is an issue on your end.  It would be useful to know how you are retrieving the nodes (obviously the create works since they are in the database).

Comment: please see my edit1 and edit2. I managed to create a leaf node with standard config which does not disappear.

Comment: I can delete the open fire's cache, stop and start the server but I can retrieve all my newly created nodes. But after one day they disappear. Maybe some openfire's "consistency check" is running every day and checks if the node configuration is valid and then caches it? But then it doesn't check after the creation..

Comment: I uninstalled openfire and install it now. In the setup there is an option for Database Connection Timeout = 1.0 days. Perhaps this is something why some of my nodes disappear after one day...But some of them stay.

Comment: This is possible UTF-8 or LATIN-1 and MySQL problem. All nodes in collection nodes which start with "W" or "U" disappear and can't be retrieved after one day. How can I get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but it might help other people:

I had this problem as well, but with the letter 'H' (as you described in your comments). I could create nodes starting with 'H' and use them correctly, but when openfire would be restarted, these nodes would not be found even though it did exist in the database.
I figured out it was because of the **root node** named '`home`'. Possibly because this also starts with an 'H'. I tried giving it several different names for the root node starting with different characters, but this would result in one or multiple other starting characters to fail.

To solve this, I named the root node '`*`' and the problems were gone! A smart way to do this is to export your database to a text file, replace all [root node] ('`home`' in my case) with '`*`', then import it again and finally restart openfire.